# Ubuntu 12.04 boots into low-graphics mode

Tags: boot, guest-session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

To prevent my brother from using my computer, I disabled the guest user account in by following the instructions from [this post](http://www.techlw.com/2012/05/disable-guest-account-in-ubuntu-1204.html).

During reboot, my brother pressed the down key and Ubuntu booted into recovery mode, I then hit the "continue boot" option and booted into low graphics mode with a black screen.

I could not see the mouse pointer so i could not continue the boot (couldn't press ok) and so had to power down the computer externally (with the button). Upon reboot, again it ran in low graphics mode but this time I was able to use the mouse. I then intended to boot and then reboot, but when I clicked OK to go into low graphics mode it goes to the boot screen (The one that says "Ubuntu" with the dots under it) and stays there indefinitely. So eventually I had to shut down my computer again.

I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> then log in and use `starts` but my desktop has no dock options or anything but the wallpaper. I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and then start a browser from the terminal.

How can I get my GUI working normally again?

Comment: Which key did he press?

Comment: the down key, sorry someone edited that out of my post.(not that i don't appreciate your editing it, thank you btw you really cleaned it up) I added back some of the important things (such as witch key presses) that accidentally removed. it is fised now

Answer (score 0):

I found the commands for when I disabled the guest account and suspecting that this could be possibly be the reason for the boot problem.

I deleted the changes I made and everything now works fine. I ended up adding the new line of code in the wrong place, at the top of the page.

I fixed it and now everything is OK.